# Send network signal over a very long distance of copper

Tags: networking, ethernet, physical-environment, cable, fiber

I have an issue were I need to interconnect 2 switches together. We've estimated that they are 1400 meters away (cabling distance).

I wanted to use a media converter to extend the signal on OS1 fiber, but I can't because I must pay a lot of monthly taxes in order to use the fiber in those premises.

What are my options to interconnect the 2 switches with only copper?

Comment: How about wireless with directional antennas?

Comment: You have to pay monthly taxes if you run your own fiber cable instead of copper?  Just curious why they would care if you run a single fiber cable vs. copper?

Comment: It's an exotic place were an authority put taxes on everything. Also, I can't have my own fiber, it will be their property and I will pay for use. And it seems that they're not really interested by copper, unlike fiber. They still charge us for copper runs though, but it's not expensive.

Comment: realistically, how much bandwidth do you need to push across this link?

Comment: 20mbps symmetrical is more than enough. After some days of research, it appears that I actually have to reach multiples switchs. So, I found that I should use an EFM device associated to multiples CPE with G.SHDSL.bis technology over bonded cooper pairs (2BASE-TL). But I'm not familiar at all with DSL technology. I feel like an ISP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You're looking for a device called an Ethernet extender/repeater](http://www.blackbox.com/Store/results.aspx/networking/extenders/n-4294958490).

The linked page is not an endorsement, so much as a matter of convenience, since this is the company I'm working with to do something similar for my employer.  You should have no trouble finding a multitude of vendors and devices to extend the range of an Ethernet signal, and there's really no interoperability/compatibility issues here.  The device just receives an electrical signal on one end, and retransmits it on the other - it's a signal amplifier, made specifically for Ethernet networking.